# How to provide helper methods to build a Map

Tags: scala, builder, scala-collections

I have a lot of client code that build `Map` using the same keys (to query MongoDB).

My idea is to provide helper methods that hide keys.

First try, I have used default parameters (cf `object Builder` below) but the client hava to deal with `Option`

I now use a builder pattern (cf `class Builder` below)

Is there a better way ?

```
class Builder {
  val m = collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
  def withA(a: Int) = {m += (("a", a))}
  def withB(b: Int) = {m += (("b", b))}
  def withC(c: Int) = {m += (("c", c))}
  def build = m.toMap
}

object Builder {
  def build1(a: Option[Int] = None, b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[Int] = None): Map[String, Int] = {
    val optPairs = List(a.map("a" -> _),
      b.map("b" -> _),
      c.map("c" -> _))
    val pairs = optPairs.flatten
    Map(pairs: _*)
  }
}

object Client {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(Builder.build1(b = Some(2)))

    println(new Builder().withB(2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution to avoid having to deal with options when calling `Builder.build1` is to define an implicit conversion to automatically wrap any value into an `Some`:

```
implicit def wrap[T]( x: T ) = Some( x )
```

And boom, you can omit the wrapping and directly do:

```
scala> Builder.build1( a = 123, c = 456 )
res1: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 123, c -> 456)
```

However, this is pretty dangerous given that options are pervasive and you don't want to pull such a general converion into scope.
To fix this you can define your own "option" class that you'll use just for the purpose of defining those optional parameters:

```
abstract sealed class OptionalArg[+T] {
  def toOption: Option[T]
}
object OptionalArg{
  implicit def autoWrap[T]( value: T  ): OptionalArg[T] = SomeArg(value)
  implicit def toOption[T]( arg: OptionalArg[T] ): Option[T] = arg.toOption
}
case class SomeArg[+T]( value: T ) extends OptionalArg[T] {
  def toOption = Some( value )
}
case object NoArg extends OptionalArg[Nothing] {
  val toOption = None
}
```

You can then redefine `Build.build1` as:

```
def build1(a: OptionalArg[Int] = NoArg, b: OptionalArg[Int] = NoArg, c: OptionalArg[Int] = NoArg): Map[String, Int]
```

And then once again, you can directly call `Build.build1` without explicitely wrapping the argument with `Some`:

```
scala> Builder.build1( a = 123, c = 456 )
res1: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 123, c -> 456)
```

With the notable difference that now we are not pulling anymore a dangerously broad conversion into cope.

---

**UPDATE**: In response to the comment below *"to go further in my need, arg can be a single value or a list, and I have awful Some(List(sth)) in my client code today"*

You can add another conversion to wrap individual parameters into one element list:

```
implicit def autoWrapAsList[T]( value: T  ): OptionalArg[List[T]] = SomeArg(List(value))
```

Then say that your method expects an optional list like this:

```
def build1(a: OptionalArg[List[Int]] = NoArg, b: OptionalArg[Int] = NoArg, c: OptionalArg[Int] = NoArg): Map[String, Int] = {
  val optPairs = List(a.map("a" -> _.sum),
    b.map("b" -> _),
    c.map("c" -> _))
  val pairs = optPairs.flatten
  Map(pairs: _*)
}
```

You can now either pass an individual element or a list (or just like before, no argument at all):

```
scala> Builder.build1( a = 123, c = 456 )
res6: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 123, c -> 456)

scala> Builder.build1( a = List(1,2,3), c = 456 )
res7: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 6, c -> 456)

scala> Builder.build1( c = 456 )
res8: Map[String,Int] = Map(c -> 456)
```

One last warning: even though we have defined our very own "option" class, it is still true that you should always use implicit conversions with some care, 
so take some time to balance whether the convenience is worth the risk in your use case.

Comment: nice trick ! Nevertheless, I find the builder approach more powerful (to reuse partial map in different client methods)

Comment: True, but it is also a lot more boilerplate to write, so you generally only go this route if there is a definitve payoff. My above solution is probably not always appropriate but is much less painfull to apply.

Comment: to go further in my need, arg can be a single value or a list, and I have awful Some(List(sth)) in my client code today.

Comment: one more time, very elegant and exactly what I need.

Comment: There is a conflict with scalaz : could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Functor[EventDao.this.OptionalArg]
[error]       contextValue.map(o => MongoDBObject("contextValue" -> o)),

Comment: I would need to see the code, but you can probably fix this by defining a `scalaz.Functor` instance for `OptionalArg`. Try to copy the definition of `OptionFunctor` from scalaz at http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0/doc.sxr/scalaz/Functor.scala.html, and then just replace `Option` with `OptionalArg`

Comment: contextValue is an OptionalArg so I don't understand why the compiler doesn't convert it implicitly to Option for calling `map` …

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46995/discussion-between-regis-jean-gilles-and-yann-moisan)